# selection model getting wrong index when working with QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: qt5, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have QStandardItemModel with own QSortFilterProxyModel to filter hidden entry in QTableView. when I select entry from this view below signal is emitted from selection model.

```
view_table->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentChanged(const QModelIndex&, const QModelIndex&)
```

Suppose I have 5 entry in list and entry no. 4 is hidden. when I select entry no. 5 above signal giving me current Index as entry no. 4 of hidden item.

how can I select correct Index (should be 5) when item is hidden in list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `QSortFilterProxyModel::mapToSource`. It takes the proxy's index and returns the corresponding index from the source model.

```
QModelIndex proxyIndex = <whatever>
QModelIndex sourceIndex = myProxyModel.mapToSource(proxyIndex);
```